# Getting holidays from the android calendar

Tags: java, android

As the title says, is it possible to get the holidays from the android calendar? For instance Christmas Eve, how can I determine that this is a holiday in my android application?

Comment: I don't think the calendar Object stores any holiday information. If you want your application to have access to that I imagine you'll have to hardcode the dates (or at least the pattern, i.e. thanksgiving is 4th thursday in november or whatever)

Comment: Okey, thanks. The problem with doing it this way is that some of the holydays doesn't fall at the same date every year.

Comment: which is why I said the part that is in parenthesis, for the holidays that don't have a set date, you'll have to hardcode what ever pattern is easiest to determine them, for instance thanks giving is always the 4th thursday in november, with that info you could write an algorithm that could tell you whether it was thanksgiving by counting the thursday's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar app does not know about holidays and other events. However, you can display in it multiple calendars so include a calendar that shows the events you want and you will have access to it via the calendar API.

For example, here is a calendar that you can add to your Google calendar:

https://www.google.com/calendar/b/0/embed?src=usa__en@holiday.calendar.google.com&gsessionid=OK

Answer (score 1):

As @Tim has said, there is no intrinsic information stored within the Calendar application about holidays. But once you figure out the algorithm for each day you can determine annually when each holiday will fall.

[This link](http://michaelthompson.org/technikos/holidays.php) might contain information that will help you determine the algorithm for each holiday.